# i am using laravel for authentication , my register works but login fails when i data dump the array for password and email is empty

Tags: laravel

I am new to laravel and seem to have issues with authentication. I created a custom login page and wanted to use the auth() function to allow registration and login. Here is my login controller it shows the connection to the blade file the registration has no issues but the login is giving me problems.
When I dd() it returns an empty array, the database seems fine proved by registration.

````
    <?php
    
    namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;
    
    use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
    use Illuminate\Http\Request;
    use auth;
    
    class LoginController extends Controller
    {
        public function index()
        {
            return view('auth.login');
        }
    
        public function store(Request $request)
        {
            
            if(!auth()->attempt($request->only('email','password'))) {
                return back()->with('status','Invalid login Details');
            }
    
            dd($request->only('email','password'));
            return redirect()->route('dashboard');
        }
    
    
    }

```

below is the blade file responsible for submitting the form to authenticate the user I suspected the session but without it I cant check


```

    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    
    <head>
      <meta name="google-signin-client_id" content="407063748479-dbmn68b26gcbeln4hevvcr97qnrg6hrd.apps.googleusercontent.com">
      <meta charset="UTF-8" />
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
      <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/64d58efce2.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="../assets-Authenticate/css/RegistrationStyling.css" />
      <title>Sign in & Sign up Form</title>
    
    </head>
    
    <body>
    
      <div class="container">
        <div class="forms-container">
          <div class="signin-signup">
            
          @if (session()->has('status'))
            {{ session('status') }}
          @endif
          
            <!--Sign In Form-->
            <form action="{{route('login')}}" class="sign-in-form" method="POST">
              @csrf
              <h2 class="title">Sign in</h2>
              <div class="input-field">
                <i class="fas fa-user"></i>
                <input type="text" placeholder="User Email" required />
    
    
              </div>
              <div class="input-field">
                <i class="fas fa-lock"></i>
                <input type="password" placeholder="Password" required pattern="(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).{8,}" title="Must contain at least one number and one uppercase and lowercase letter, and at least 8 or more characters"/>
              
    
              </div>
              <input type="submit" value="Login" class="btn solid" />
              <div class="reset">
                <a href="PasswordReset.html">Forgot Password ?</a>
              </div>
             
            </form> 
```
````

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to add a name to your inputs try:

```
<input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" required pattern="(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).{8,}" title="Must contain at least one number and one uppercase and lowercase letter, and at least 8 or more characters"/>
```

And

```
<input type="text" name="email" placeholder="User Email" required />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't run auth without adding a name use this code in the input tag instead.

```
<input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" 
    required pattern="(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).{8,}" 
    title="Must contain at least one number and one uppercase and lowercase 
    letter, and at least 8 or more characters"/>

<input type="text" name="email" placeholder="User Email" required />
```